# Why doesn't the select drops down?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am trying to change the contents of a `<div>` whenever it is hovered. But, while doing this I am encountering a problem that the select is not dropping down. How to correct this? `appendChild()` method might solve the problem but I am trying to do it only with `.innerHTML` .

```html
<div id = "navigation" onmouseover = "navigationAnimate()">
Fun
</div>

<script>
function navigationAnimate() {
    navigation.innerHTML = "<select>  <option>Finance</option> <option>Health</option><option>Fun</option><option selected>Maths</option><option>Conveters</option><option>Chronology</option><option>Sciences</option><option>Miscellaneous</option></select>";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `mouseover` event keeps firing for the children you mouse over, and changing the children every time. Basically it keeps replacing the children over and over while trying to use it.

For example, if you remove the event listener on the first `mouseover` event, it will set once and be done.

```html
<div id = "navigation" onmouseover = "navigationAnimate()">
Fun
</div>

<script>
function navigationAnimate(){
    navigation.innerHTML = "<select>  <option>Finance</option> <option>Health</option><option>Fun</option><option selected>Maths</option><option>Conveters</option><option>Chronology</option><option>Sciences</option><option>Miscellaneous</option></select>";
    navigation.onmouseover = '';
}
</script>
```

On a side note, I'd recommend looking into using `addEventListener`, rather than event attributes; it's much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

`Cause everytime you move cursor under **#navigation** block it change the content . 
You need to remove attribute "onmouseover" after change the content;

```
<div id = "navigation" onmouseover = "navigationAnimate()">
Fun
</div>

<script>
function navigationAnimate(){

navigation.innerHTML = "<select>  <option>Finance</option> <option>Health</option><option>Fun</option><option selected>Maths</option><option>Conveters</option><option>Chronology</option><option>Sciences</option><option>Miscellaneous</option></select>";
navigation.removeAttribute('onmouseover');
}

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz49m7ko/

Answer (score 1):

Here problem is that you call function onMouseOver event of javascript so it will continuously call the function when your mouse is moving on your div or content.

Here I try to overcome it using condition and modified your existing code. Hope it will work for you. Best of luck.

```
<div id="navigation" onmouseover="navigationAnimate();">
 Fun
</div>

<script>
var flag = true;
function navigationAnimate(){
 if(flag){
    flag = false;
    navigation.innerHTML = "<select><option>Finance</option> <option>Health</option><option>Fun</option><option selected>Maths</option><option>Conveters</option><option>Chronology</option><option>Sciences</option><option>Miscellaneous</option></select>";
    }
}
</script>
```